# How to finish edge of tiled shower with metal outside drywall?

Tags: shower, tile

I have a newly tiled shower that was put in with a metal edging piece.

However you can still see the edge of the cement board underneath it where it meets the wall.

How do I finish this?

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something? The wall to the right is not finished when that is done it may be a trim board is all that is needed.

Comment: The wall to the right is finished. The cement board was added on top of the drywall, not made flush with it.

Comment: I am talking of the big divots in the mud and stud? Or frame work showing. Maybe another photo that will provide perspective would be helpful.

Comment: A metal "T" edging piece would have worked better, that would cover the edge of the tile and also the exposed cement board. Otherwise I agree with Ed Beal that a piece of trim would be all you need.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry haven’t sanded the last coat of mud, exposed frame is the window. I assumed it would have a T edge but wasn’t sure if I’m supposed to add a layer of mesh and more mud  in the crack. The break away trim board doesn’t seem to work in that area very well. Atleast not the one I have.

Comment: It looks like this edge is turning 90 degrees from the tiled wall. If that's the case, I would consider tile this edge and grout the seam.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to finish the 90degree transition where the metal trim meets the drywall.

First, I would clean up the metal trim. Scrape off or use some kind of adhesive remover to remove any residue. You may need to buff/polish it with some fine grit sandpaper.

For the transition i would use caulk, If you feel it may see a lot of moisture then use 100% mold/mildew resistant silicone. (*after painting the wall*)

If not then a paint-able caulk (*before painting the wall*)  that would be able to accept the paint color you choose for the wall.